# Is it correct to call registerForRemoteNotifications() all the time app starts?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, usernotifications

From Apple Doc example on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/registering_your_app_with_apns

`UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` is called all the time when app starts:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
           [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   // Override point for customization after application launch.

   UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
   return true
}
```

Is it normal? Or we should use boolean preference and check if it's not registered and call it?

Also I need to request authorization from user to show notifications but in an appropriate place (e.g., in my Settings View Controller where I have a switch to enable/disable notifications)

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
```

And it seems in this case I have to move all code from `AppDelegate`, e.g.: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift to my Settings View Controller, even `registerForRemoteNotifications()`.

So all delegates related to notifications (registering, receiving) will be in Settings View Controller. Is it going to work? Will I receive notifications in that place when App is not running?

Or where am I supposed to place different parts of the code?

**Update**

Also why they don't use

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { settings in
    if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions) { granted, error in
            if granted {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    } else if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
        //
    } else if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
})
```

instead of

```
let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
  options: authOptions,
  completionHandler: {_, _ in })

UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

?

Comment: Generally you can leave everything in your code as it is and control the notifications from your backend. You can make a API call to enable or disable notifications from your settings viewController. In this case the notifications settings will be specific for each user(assuming that your app settings are separate for each user). 
So when sending a push notification from your server you can check if the user's notification setting is true or false and then send accordingly.

Comment: @CedanMisquith so how often should I call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` and where should I call it?

Comment: You can leave it as it is. I have used it this way in couple of my apps. Since you can catch all incoming notifications only in `AppDelegate` you should call `registerForRemoteNotifications` in AppDelegate it self. And you can call it every time your app runs its totally fine. It is mentioned this way in the Documentation as well. You have implemented the right way. You just need to control the toggle of notification `ON` & `OFF` in the way that i mentioned above.

Comment: @CedanMisquith but `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` definitely should not be in AppDelegate then.

Comment: Yes the authorization part you can choose where to put it. But generally all apps request the users permission to receive notification during the first launch, so you can put it in your first view controller. If you have noticed almost all apps request for all permission during the first launch of the app. But its your call. You can choose to request authorization at any time. But until you do so, your user will not receive any notification. So better to get it out of the way at the start.

Comment: @CedanMisquith see my updated question about `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings`

Comment: I checked your update. Are you using Local notifications or Push notifications ???

Comment: @CedanMisquith Firebase Messaging (of course Push Notifications)

Comment: Ok so then the approach you mentioned in your updated question is the better way. Its more clean and it captures any possibility of the user denying permissions at any time. I think in the link that you mentioned they have not used your approach as they are just showing the important lines of code and not really bothered in error handling or not bothered in handling all execeptions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the right approach is to call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` all the time app starts. Calling it only when user has authorized push notifications is dangerous. In fact, user, initially, could deny authorization, but then he could turn on notifications from device Settings app. In this case, app will not receive notifications until user reopens the app and this could be happen much later.

Comment: That is absolutely incorrect, there is no harm in deferring the push registration! This is a much better UX as well. When I launch the new app and it throws push prompt right away, I ALWAYS deny it, and two: I immediately lower my expectations about the quality of this app

Comment: @nalexn I think you misunderstood my answer. `registerForRemoteNotifications()` doesn't prompt any alert.